# What is the correct way to use classes in CSS?

Tags: html, css, code-organization

I see people creating classes for each object, for example:

```css
.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;    
  justify-content: center;    
  color: white;    
}

.images-wrapper {
  display: flex;    
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper"></div>
<div class="images-wrapper"></div>
```

But also, I see people creating classes by attributes, as for example in Bootstrap:

```css
.centered-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-wrapper {
  color: blue;
}

.images-wrapper {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered-content content-wrapper"></div>
<div class="centered-content images-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: The first one should probably be with IDs, not classes.

Comment: this is really an open question, open to debate, some folks came with naming conventions / solutions such as BEM, SMACSS, here is a good lecture I think for you http://getbem.com/introduction/

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol the only problem with IDs there is you could make your life difficult further down the line with specificity issues.

Comment: No class should be named independently of the content that it is classifying. Since you provide no content, neither class naming strategy can be valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a group of elements for which you wish to apply a certain styling create a class, if you have a single element for which you wish to apply a style create an ID. I beleive this is the most common and  generally considered best system by which to use CSS.

Answer (score 1):

when you have style that's repeated in your html you maybe need create one class for all DOM thats use this style.

For example

```
<style>
   .box1{
         width: 300px;
         background-color: blue;
   }
   .subbox2{
         width: 30px;
         background-color: green;
   }
  .center{
         margin: auto;
         position: absolute;
  }
</style>

<div class="center box1">
  <div class= "center subbox2"></div>
</div>
```